# How can I make this code work for custom 'Facebook Like Box'

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress

I found a tutorial with a demo on customizing the 'Facebook Like Box'; it works great on that demo. I grabbed the code, and inserted my page's ID via https://graph.facebook.com/ and inserted it in the sidebar code widget of my Wordpress site. It begans to load, then outputs this error;

'**Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.**'

Where/how can I fix that in the code? Do I have to update the ID in another place as well?

Code:

```
<div id="facebook">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">FB.init("fd161b28d6338cb852d8ed87878f67c3");</script>
    <!-- FBML <fb:fan profile_id="284177564941187" connections="18" width="403" height="360" css="http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/facebook/demo/style.css?5"></fb:fan> FBML -->
    <script src="http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/facebook/demo/js/fbvalidate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</div>
```

***Edit:*** I'm resorting to this code in attempt to solve my general question with 'Facebook Like Box' - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995678/facebook-like-box-close-thumbnail-padding-html5-iframe-v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using FeatureLoader? That's deprecated and marked for removal shortly.

The Like Box code can be obtained from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Comment: Yes - I know I can get the general like box there. How can I customize it is the main reason why I looked to find different code. I just want to close the padding displayed in the rows of thumbs.

Comment: You may have to implement something yourself - the method you're using   (FeatureLoader.js) is earmarked to be removed - so going down this road is only going to cause problems for you later

Comment: Any suggestions as to how to start implementing custom facebook elements and widgets on my own?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing, if you just want to grab the content from a page, a simple call in the Graph API to /{page_id}/feed will give you the recent posts on a page's wall and you can format them however you wish