# Customizing like box, close padding, remove names

Tags: facebook, html, iframe, xfbml

I'm trying to remove the 'names' below the thumb nails photos and close the padding to compress it to be smaller in height.

*Here's where I'm failing;*

http://jsfiddle.net/cam77/4havc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant manipulate anything inside a iframe that isnt in your same domain/subdomain. (in your sample, the iframe src is www.facebook.com).

Its the crossdomain police.

Comment: Thanks, but how could I customize then?

Comment: You can create a custom widget using facebook tools: check this link http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-add-a-custom-facebook-like-box-to-your-site

Comment: I tried using that link as a resource and it's code. I couldn't get anything to implement, and even posted about it on here - everyone said that the resource and code is about depreciated so apparently not usable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995357/how-can-i-make-this-code-work-for-custom-facebook-like-box